# How to synchronize custom ID column with table's primary key column

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

Primarily, sorry for being too descriptive.
I am storing patient's info in sql db by creating a custom ID field "PatientID" and I have a primary key field "ID". PatientID has a pattern "PID-1" or "PID-2" so on and so forth. I want to synchronize both IDs. Like if table's ID for "John" is 4 then its patientID should also be "PID-4". For this, I have done some coding like if no record exist then start saving patientID from "PID-1" and then for all next record first find the max id of patient from ID field and increment it by 1 and concatenate it with "PID" + (tableID+1).

```
 ID    PatientID
 1      PID-1
 2      PID-2
 3      PID-3
 4      PID-4
```

Now, for an instance, while adding more record an exception is thrown although record is not saved but ID gets incremented. And here comes the problem. Suppose, some bug comes and record for ID 5 could not be saved in the db, after fixing that bug when program runs correctly it put the ID 6 rather than 5. And for the patientID it puts "PID-5" due to MAX query. From here both IDs start being distinct. Same problem for deleting, if I am deleting last record from above table i.e, 4 and PID-4, the next record's ID would be 5 while PatientID would be "PID-4". This was the whole problematic picture of handling both IDs from my side. Any alternate solution or any modification in my idea or any better idea then mine would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds too critical, but what is the point of this `PatientId`? Why do you want to have an additional redundant surrogate id, only a much a less efficient one stored as a characters by appending a useless prefix to it?

Comment: @SidraM: displaying 4 or PID-4 is just a matter of string formatting. I would not store both values [using two columns].

Comment: @SqlZim.. That's because every patient has its alloted id to check record against it. Just like in the school students are assigned roll number etc

Comment: Well.. Problem is solved. Solution was suggested by@Christos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server you could create a computed column for this purpose:

```
ALTER TABLE Patient DROP COLUMN PatientID;
GO
ALTER TABLE Patient ADD COLUMN PatientID AS ('PID-'+CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(15));
```

For more info regarding computed columns, please have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table).

**Note**: I assumed that your table's name is `Patient`. You have to change this correspondingly if this is not the name of your table.

Comment: If I add a computed  column like you suggested what effect will it put on my C# code. I don't have to check for maximum value then?

Comment: Actually you would only read this value on select statements. You don't have to do anything else regarding this column. Each time you run a select statement on your table this value would be calculated if you don't have choosen to be a persisted computed column. If I remember correctly there two kinds of computed columns those that are persisted and those that are calculated on the fly, when the select statement is executed by the db engine.

Comment: So to answer your question you have to remove anything related with this column except from the corresponding property (I suppose that you have a class tha represents a Patient record and in this class you have a property called PatientID, I refer to this property.)

Comment: super duper solution. Problem solved.. :D Thank you so much

Comment: @SidraM You are welcome dude ! I am glad that I helped :)

Comment: One more question please. When the form loads which asks for the details of patient, I have given a locked textbox in which new patient's ID is  pre-written. Like I want to enter a new record for "Mia" so, when the form opens patient id PID-5 should be written there for Mia. So for the solution you provided what method I would follow to put the ID on textbox on form load? or any other alternate?

Comment: When the form you use to insert new patients is loaded the PatientID wouldn't have any value. So in the UI you shouldn't show anything about this. If you use the same VIew for edit of patient's data, you should only show the corresponding textbox only when the value of PatientID is not not empty.

Comment: Hmmm got your point. Thanks a lot for making things clear. :)